# Как поставить фоновый рисунок в RichBox C#?

Tags: c#

Мне интересно, вот создаются электронные блокноты и у них задний фон не белый, а разноцветный, в клетку, в линию. Вопрос: как можно добиться такого? Чтобы строки оставались как обычно, но в фон поставить рисунок в клетку, в линию? Рассмотрел RichBox в C#, но там не обнаружил пункт image. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем секрет?

Или же сделать Rich TextBox прозрачным

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум есть свойство Canvas, которое есть у любого визуального элемента.

P.S. Проверил -- оказалось наврал, видимо какайто глюк памяти.

Тогда делаем так (WPF):

```
<RichTextBox ...>
            <RichTextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/WpfApplication1;component/Images/pic.jpg"/>
            </RichTextBox.Background>
 </RichTextBox>
```

WinForms: похоже подобной функциональности RichTextBox не предоставляет :(, надо брать другой компонент от сторонних разработчиков.

Comment: извиняюсь, но на чем вы написали этот код??? Странно что теги, да и у RichBox нет свойства .Background. Я не понял ничего если честно

Comment: давайте начнем с начала, на чем пишите... выше -- это WPF

Comment: форма C#-овская

Comment: Имеете ввиду WinForm? ...или что-то другое?

Comment: да, WinForm